# Getting Equation From Trendlines Once They've Been Formated

Tags: excel, vba

Good Morning,

This problem has been plaguing me since before Christmas. I have a graph that I apply trendlines to then format the trendline to get a more detailed equation for, 6 Sig Figs rather than excels default mode. However when I come to extract the equation of the trendlines, sometimes I get the full 6 sig fig version of the equation and other times I get the default version. I can see no logic behind why this jumps from case to case, although I'm sure there is a reason for this. The code that I use is below (I'm also sure that there may be far more efficient ways to code this - currently just trying to get it to work)

```
Set t = My_Chart.Chart.SeriesCollection(X).Trendlines(1)
t.DataLabel.NumberFormat = "0.00000E+00"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Eqn_Len = Len(t.DataLabel.Text)
LHS_Len = Round(Eqn_Len / 2)
RHS_Len = Eqn_Len - LHS_Len
LHS = Left(t.DataLabel.Text, LHS_Len)
RHS = Right(t.DataLabel.Text, RHS_Len)
Equation_Formula = LHS & RHS
Cells(95, 1) = Equation_Formula
Equation_Formula_Main = Replace(Equation_Formula, "y=", "")
Equation_Formula_Main = Replace(Equation_Formula_Main, "x3", "x^3")
Equation_Formula_Main = Replace(Equation_Formula_Main, "x2", "x^2")
Cells(95, 1).Value = Equation_Formula_Main
Equation_Formula_Main = Right(Equation_Formula_Main, Len(Equation_Formula_Main) - 2)
```

The Trendline I'm using is a 3rd Order Polynomial with about 15 -30 points, dependant on the data. Can anyone see any reason why this would be the case?

To aid, I've added an example. 
I have defined all lengths as double, the variables that contain strings as strings and t as a trendline

My current equation = "y = -8.80186E-09X^3 + 1.28815E-04X^2 - 5.17488E-01X + 7.06521E+02. This gives the variable `Eqn_Len` a value of 42, which is clearly wrong, however the value of `Len(t.DataLabel.Text)` is equal to 63. Following through the code the variable `LHS` becomes "y = -9E-09X^3 + 0.0001" and the variable `RHS` becomes "x^2 - 0.5175X + 706.52. You can see that this equation is excels default version of the trendline rather than the formated version that it should be.

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide plus any light you can shed on this rather small but annoying issue.

Comment: That's a really strange way to approach this in my opinion, when you could just calculate them yourself directly from the data: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/

Comment: @Rory, I'm using this approach as each trendline has different amounts of data which are not always sequential, so I don't believe this could work although I may be wrong, didn't spend much time looking into this method

Comment: They should be the same calculations your chart trendline does.